# Undertown. Async responce with another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, http, asynchronous, undertow

I try to realize how to build an true-async http server with Undertow. How to send a response asynchronously if I have another thread which one is processing a request already?
I wrote code like this:

```java
    Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
            .setHandler(exchange -> {
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).thenAccept(string -> {
                    exchange.getResponseHeaders()
                            .put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
                    exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
                    exchange.endExchange();
                }).exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    System.out.println(throwable.toString());
                    return null;
                });
            }).build();
    server.start();
```

but this server response 200 with no data and in logs

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000127: Response has already been sent

When I use io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange#dispatch(java.lang.Runnable) method like this:

```java
    Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
            .setHandler(exchange -> {

                exchange.dispatch(() -> {

                    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }).thenAccept(string -> {
                        exchange.getResponseHeaders()
                                .put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE,"text/plain");
                        exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
                        exchange.endExchange();
                    }).exceptionally(throwable -> {
                        System.out.println(throwable.toString());
                        return null;
                    });

                });
            }).build();
    server.start();
```

of course a response "Hello World" as expected but server creates new thread for every request!

(jvisualvm after 10 parallel requests)
[image: jvisualvm after 10 parallel requests]

Comment: P.S. I run it in a main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `dispatch()` without passing an executor, like this:

```
exchange.dispatch(() -> {
    //...
});
```

it will dispatch it to the XNIO worker thread pool. It will not necessarily "create new thread for every request".

If you want to not dispatch it to another thread, you should do this:

```
exchange.dispatch(SameThreadExecutor.INSTANCE, () -> {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

the undertow not support this way,

i create a new project to solve it:

https://github.com/hank-whu/undertow-async

```
package io.undertow.async.pingpong;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import io.undertow.async.handler.AsyncHttpHandler;
import io.undertow.async.io.PooledByteBufferInputStream;
import io.undertow.async.io.PooledByteBufferOutputStream;
import io.undertow.connector.ByteBufferPool;
import io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange;
import io.undertow.util.StatusCodes;

public class PingPongAsyncHttpHandler extends AsyncHttpHandler {

    @Override
    protected void handleAsyncRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange, PooledByteBufferInputStream content)
            throws Exception {

        CompletableFuture//
                .completedFuture(content)// init
                .thenApplyAsync(this::readBytesAndClose)// read
                .thenApplyAsync(bytes -> {// write
                    ByteBufferPool byteBufferPool = exchange.getConnection().getByteBufferPool();
                    PooledByteBufferOutputStream output = new PooledByteBufferOutputStream(byteBufferPool);
                    write(output, bytes);
                    return output;
                })//
                .thenAcceptAsync(output -> send(exchange, StatusCodes.OK, output));
    }

    private byte[] readBytesAndClose(PooledByteBufferInputStream content) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[content.available()];
            content.read(bytes);
            return bytes;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {// must close it
                content.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void write(PooledByteBufferOutputStream output, byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            output.write("asycn response: ");
            output.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```